# navbar position changes when tried to fix the navbar using position fixed

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar, positioning

I tried to position my navbar with a brand name on the left and links to other sections on the pages to the right side by using flex container and giving justify-content:end; property to the left side containing links .everything works fine until I tried to position my navbar fixed at the top by giving position:fixed.But now the justify-content property is not working.Any solution??
Thanks

Comment: Can you produce some code of the problem you are facing?